# Performance testing server by sending binary data over socket

Tags: binary-data, performance-testing

I have a Server program that accepts multiple connections over TCP carrying binary streams of data. I have generated data in multiple binary files. I would like to test the server performance by creating multiple Client threads that will read a binary file, connect to server and stream the data to the server and then finally report statistics on how long it took to send data over that connection to the server. The data is of proprietary format and not over http but jsut a stream of variable length binary messages with a length field at the beginning(4 bytes). No response is sent by the server(other than TCP acks)

I can implement it but wanted to check whether there is any load testing tool that supports this functionality.

Comment: Check the answer to [How can I measure the performance and TCP RTT of my server code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102268/how-can-i-measure-the-performance-and-tcp-rtt-of-my-server-code).